# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have an application with Laravel 4, that runs in localhost correctly,
but when I uploaded it in my host I received the error .

app>config>database.php file is:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'forum',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

And bootstrap>start.php is:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
'local' => array('homestead'),
));
```

Comment: Your username or password is incorrect. Consult your host's support pages/documentation in order to find out how to log into your database. If that fails then make use of the support -- that is what it is there for.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Even though I changed the `config` details in the `.env` file, I was getting the Access denied error. Running the above command will clear configuration cache file and hence laravel will read the fresh data from the `.env` file.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This command is only available in laravel 5, if I am correct.

Answer (score 3):

You must find out the credentials of Database host, Database Name , Database Username and Database Password . (If any prefix for tables too) and then replace it with the current credentials.

Use the concept of environments and store values in ENV variables :

> http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration

You can store Env Variables as array in `.{ENV_NAME}.env.php` and access those variables as `$_ENV['variable_name']`.

Comment: please explain brightly.. I dont Know about environment in Laravel 4,thank you

Comment: I edited my database.php and added prefix for DatabaseName,UserName but i recieved this error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should add double-quotes for password in env:

```sh
# Config: database
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD="db_password"
```

and

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Using double quotes around my DB_PASSWORD value fixed my issue. It appears that some special characters must be wrapped in double quotes for proper encoding. This is relevant in Laravel 7.x.

Answer (score 2):

Check your mysql database is running perfectly or not. Then check you db user `root` in mysql with no password and restart your server.

Comment: yes root user has password, and i edited database.php,but i have this error yet...!

Answer (score 0):

*Laravel Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

**In .env** I changed add ' ' in line '**user**' and '**password**':

***DB_USERNAME=user***

***DB_PASSWORD=password***

to:

***DB_USERNAME='user'***

***DB_PASSWORD='password'***

Worked for me!

**Run -> php artisan optimize:clear**

Good luck <3