# Run a laravel application

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am absolutely new to laravel. I have an open source laravel application for which I have downloaded the code. I was able to get the home page running using these links:

- https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-16-04/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/764782/install-laravel-5-on-ubuntu-16-04
- http://idroot.net/linux/install-laravel-ubuntu-16-04/
- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

none of the other webpages are running. I have to manually change the path in the address bar from localhost/public to localhost/public/index.php. Even after this, the webpage that executes, shows no css.If I try to register a user, I get

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value

I have referred to the following links in an attempt to solve the issue but no use -

- [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875714/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-laravel)
- https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#routing
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart#database-migrations
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database

I don't have any data in the database as I cannot understand how to import it. My directory structure is

```
/var/www/laravelApplicaton
-app/
-artisan
-bootstrap/
-composer.json
-composer.lock
-config/
-database/
-gulpfile.js
-package.json
-phpunit.xml
-public/
-readme.md
-resources/
-routes/
-server.php
-storage/
-tests/
-vendor/
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04 server; Php7.0.

Comment: I think you need to read the tutorials online and try harder. Please come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: @self - can you suggest any particular tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

OK, you're using Laravel 5.3 as your folder structure shows. There if you closely look there's no any `.env` file. Do create that because Laravel first seeks for `.env` file for configurations if that doesn't exists, then it looks for key value pairs in configuration folder i.e config. So if you have got `.env` file do change database information there or you can change that from `/config/database.php`. But the good practice is to use `.env` file on development machine. It's shown here in this link, the way to create `.env` file:

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-16-04/

And for "username doesn't have a default value" issue, you have not passed value for "username" while inserting, this problem arises if you have `username` field that can't be null in your **database** structure.

The best option to play with Laravel is to use composer. Please follow the laravel 5.3 documentation for installation process.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation

And for beginner Laracast.com have very nice series to get started with Laravel from scratch, I myself have used this tutorial series to get started with laravel.

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/1

Do check all those episodes out, once you finish you'll be now very much familiar with Laravel.

Hope this helps you.