# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, xampp

I make php artisan make:auth and tried to register as a new user then I get the error. I am using Xampp for MySQL and make a database name 'pari' and set user: root and password: root. After starting xampp apache and SQL server and PHP artisan serve on cmd I get the same error every time.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = avinashjk1620@gmail.com)

Step 1: I have changed .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pari
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

and restart using php artisan serve , but again it gave that error.

Step 2: I have changed config\database.php to-

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'pari'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

but it again gave that same error. 
Step 3: I tried

```
  php artisan cache:clear 
  php artisan config:clear
```

but again get same error.

Step 4: After removing password from phpmyadmin and .env and database.php I get new error-

```
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pari.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = avinashjk1620@gmail.com)
```

How can i fixed this error Please help me.

Comment: remove you cache and restart the server

Comment: do config:clear

Comment: I has remove cache and congifured but again getting same error

Comment: does your sql has a password?? try logging in with the credentials you have provided, and remove the port once to check again

Comment: yes password is root. I have changed it many times and tried but getting same error

Comment: To fix `Base table or view not found:` you need to `php artisan migrate` to  create the tables.

Comment: Yes i tried but get error ("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your database was created using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation. This should fix your 1071 error.

Alternatively you can add `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` to your `boot()` method in `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`.

Edit: Make sure to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`.

Comment: after adding that in boot() method and runninh php artisan migrate i get error  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found

  at D:\Php mine\Laravel\happyHome\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php: 16

Comment: Edited my answer, you need to add the `Schema` class's namespace

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all of your fields are set up correctly especially your password.

```
    $this->server = "localhost";
    $this->username = "root";
    $this->password = "";
    $this->dbName = "dbone";
    $this->charset = "utf8mb4";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do following things once you changed the credential

```
php artisan config:clear 
restart php artisan
```

Comment: Weird. Can you confirm you are restarting the artisan on right project? Sometimes I do mistakenly with a different project. Silly mistake.

Comment: tried all ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875714/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-laravel

Comment: Yes , i tried by removing  password and get same error

Comment: If its new one then delete the project and create new one

Comment: I has already tried that i make new project outside htdocs in xampp and also inside that folder but same error everywhere.

Comment: Woah, You tried everything :p. Try to restart mysql server.

Comment: After removing password i get new error:- SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pari.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = avinashjk1620@gmail.com)

Comment: Ah, First ran migrate? to create users table?

Comment: When i has root password then i tried that but getting same error. After removing password i try php artisan migrate it give error.

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

Comment: clear users table from database and php artisan migrate:reset

Comment: then do migrate

Comment: I have done but get same error ("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")

Answer (score 1):

If there is still the problems with the connectivity to the server while on the Cpanel, I solve it by putting the password into a "" quotes and boom everything was responding correctly

> DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=sppro
>   DB_USERNAME=sppro DB_PASSWORD="sppro123#"

Done I was able to login into the files

Answer (score 0):

Just only change `.env` file and **DON'T** change `config/database.php` file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 or IP address
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE='your database name'
DB_USERNAME='your username'
DB_PASSWORD='your password'
```

**it works for me!**

Answer (score 0):

I am using xampp on ubuntu 22.04 and I solved the problem using below steps

1. Go to User Accounts in phpmyadmin using http://localhost/phpmyadmin
2. Select the user from the list
3. Click Login information
4. Under the Host name dropdown select localhost. The default value was %
5. Click Go

I never faced this problem when I was using xampp on a windows machine.